# Saying Yekum Purkan after the Minyan is already up to Av HaRachamim or Ashrei

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shabbat, minyan, tzibur-community

The Halacha is that a individual not Davening with a Minyan does not say Yekum Purkan. Suppose you are in Shul and for some reason the Chazan finished Yekum Purkan and is already up to Av HaRachamim or Ashrei can you as an individual say it now or you are too late?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sefer Ishei Yisrael on Tefila mentions in the name of HaRav Chaim Kanievsky that one can recite Yekum Purkan alone so long he was in the Shul when the congregation said it.

Comment: Dayan Raskin points out the same thing in his notes on the Baal Hatanya's Siddur (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=336, note 101).

Answer (score 3):

In my siddur (סידור קול יעקב החדש) it specifically says one who davens alone **in his house (בביתו)**, which would seem to imply that it's okay to say it.